# blender export gltf crash on 20.10, but working on 20.04

Tags: blender, 20.10

I use default cube scene.
I tried both snap installation and without an installation, running from extracted folder
blender-2.90.1-linux64.tar.xz
blender-2.83.8-linux64.tar.xz
before ugrade to new operation system ubuntu 20.10
I was using ubuntu 20.04 and it was working
now on ubuntu 20.10 other export methods works. just gltf crashes
I run from terminal to get error message but I dont know how to find the "core dumped" file

:~/$ blender
Read prefs: /home/u/.config/blender/2.90/config/userpref.blend
/run/user/1000/snap.blender/gvfs/ non-existent directory
found bundled python: /snap/blender/47/2.90/python
Aborted (core dumped)

:~/Downloads/blender-2.90.1-linux64$ ./blender
Read prefs: /home/u/.config/blender/2.90/config/userpref.blend
found bundled python: /home/u/Downloads/blender-2.90.1-linux64/2.90/python
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: I am getting a similar issue in Ubuntu 20.10 but at program startup whenever I have certain add-ons enabled, like RetopoFlow, MeshMachine, and BoxCutter.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a workaround for this. It seems like the snap and official Blender builds have a Python mismatch and that's what's causing Blender to crash when running or loading certain addons.

[This PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/blender?field.series_filter=groovy) seems to have a fairly complete Blender 2.90 build that works with Ubuntu 20.10. I've tested with MeshMachine, RetopoFlow, and BoxCutter.

Make sure to install the python3-numpy package, as quite a few addons depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

this crash is caused by a bug in Python 3.7.7 which ships with Blender, see our findings here: https://developer.blender.org/T84752

As discussed in the bug report, you can either install Flatpak version or try this workaround:
Open your Blender installation's directory and edit the file `[blender version]/python/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py` by commenting out line 273 (just add # in front of it):

```
#CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(lambda: None)
```

Save file, restart Blender and see if it works. Or just wait for a Blender update, they might fix it soon.